# TFS 2012 API - Create local-workspace or switch from server- to local-workspace

Tags: tfs-sdk

Is it possible to create a local workspace, or switch from a server workspace to a local one only with the TFS-API?

I have nothing installed on the machine where i want to archieve this and use only a console application with the TFS-API dlls. If i, under this circumstances, create a workspace, it will be set to IsLocal=false. But i need to have a local one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the help the following options are available from the TF workspace command

```
tf workspace /new [/noprompt] [/template:workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
             [/computer:computername] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)]
             [workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
             [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
             [/permission:(Private|PublicLimited|Public)]
             [/location:(local|server)]
             [/filetime:(current|checkin)]
             [/login:username,[password]]

tf workspace [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
             [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)]
             [/newname:workspacename] [workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
             [/newowner:ownername] [/computer:computername]
             [/permission:(Private|PublicLimited|Public)]
             [/location:(local|server)]
             [/filetime:(current|checkin)]
             [/login:username,[password]]
```

Comment: Hi Just TFS. I do not work with PowerShell Commands, I do with the .NET API. Therefore I am searching for a solution with the .NET API.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated the need of at least Team Explorer (Which installes also VS2012 Shell) for changing a programatically created workspace from server to local.

It may also work with the powershell command, but i dont want to use these, if possible.

Maybe there is a way to do the switch only with code, but i did not found any in time.